# Manual simulation of Markov Chain in R

Tags: r, statistics, probability, markov-chains

> Consider the Markov chain with state space *S = {1, 2}*, transition matrix
>
> [image]
>
> and initial distribution *α = (1/2, 1/2)*.
>
> 1. Simulate 5 steps of the Markov chain (that is, simulate *X<sub>0</sub>*, *X<sub>1</sub>*, . . . , *X<sub>5</sub>*). Repeat the simulation 100
>      times. Use the results of your simulations to solve the following problems.
>
>    - Estimate *P(X<sub>1</sub> = 1|X<sub>0</sub> = 1)*. Compare your result with the exact probability.

My solution:

```
# returns Xn 
func2 <- function(alpha1, mat1, n1) 
{
  xn <- alpha1 %*% matrixpower(mat1, n1+1)

  return (xn)
}

alpha <- c(0.5, 0.5)
mat <- matrix(c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 1), nrow=2, ncol=2)
n <- 10


for (variable in 1:100) 
{
   print(func2(alpha, mat, n))
}
```

---

What is the difference if I run this code once or 100 times (as is said in the problem-statement)?

How can I find the conditional probability from here on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

```
alpha <- c(1, 1) / 2
mat <- matrix(c(1 / 2, 0, 1 / 2, 1), nrow = 2, ncol = 2) # Different than yours
```

be the initial distribution and the transition matrix. Your `func2` only finds n-th step distribution, which isn't needed, and doesn't simulate anything. Instead we may use

```
chainSim <- function(alpha, mat, n) {
  out <- numeric(n)
  out[1] <- sample(1:2, 1, prob = alpha)
  for(i in 2:n)
    out[i] <- sample(1:2, 1, prob = mat[out[i - 1], ])
  out
}
```

where `out[1]` is generated using only the initial distribution and then for subsequent terms we use the transition matrix.

Then we have

```
set.seed(1)
# Doing once
chainSim(alpha, mat, 1 + 5)
# [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

so that the chain initiated at 2 and got stuck there due to the specified transition probabilities.

Doing it for 100 times we have

```
# Doing 100 times
sim <- replicate(chainSim(alpha, mat, 1 + 5), n = 100)
rowMeans(sim - 1)
# [1] 0.52 0.78 0.87 0.94 0.99 1.00
```

where the last line shows how often we ended up in state 2 rather than 1. That gives one (out of many) reasons why 100 repetitions are more informative: we got stuck at state 2 doing just a single simulation, while repeating it for 100 times we explored more possible paths.

Then the conditional probability can be found with

```
mean(sim[2, sim[1, ] == 1] == 1)
# [1] 0.4583333
```

while the true probability is 0.5 (given by the upper left entry of the transition matrix).

Comment: What is being effected by `set.seed(1)` here? Where is a random number being generated?

Comment: @user366312, it makes the simulation results reproducible - if you run this code, including `set.seed(1)`, you will get the same numbers. Using any number other than `1` is also fine, it will "fix" the random generator in a different state. See `?set.seed`.

Comment: @user366312, `sample(0:1, 1, prob = alpha)` generates the initial number, while `sample(0:1, 1, prob = mat[1 + out[i - 1], ])` generates all the following ones.

Comment: So, in essence, `seed()` is effecting `sample()`?

Comment: @user366312, exactly.

Comment: @user366312, I had incorrectly assumed states to be 0 and 1 rather than 1 and 2. I updated the answer accordingly where everything is mostly the same, except for the conditional probability.

Comment: Why are you always doing `1+5` i.e. `6` steps?

Comment: @user366312, because your question says *Simulate 5 steps of the Markov chain (that is, simulate X0, X1, . . . , X5)*. So, I simulate X0, ..., X5, which is less ambiguous than "5 steps".