# Understanding matrix sub-setting: `mat[2, mat[1, ] == 1] == 1`

Tags: r

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55830847/159072).

I am having trouble understanding the following:

> ```
>    mean(sim[2, sim[1, ] == 1] == 1)
>    # [1] 0.4583333
> ```

If the previous is possible, Why does the following give 0?

```
 > sim = matrix(c(1,2,1,2,1,2), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
 > sim
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    1
 [2,]    2    1    2
 > 
 > # list 2nd row of the matrix
 > row2 <- sim[2, sim[1, ] == 1] == 1
 > row2
 [1] FALSE FALSE
 > 
 > mean(row2)
 [1] 0
```

Comment: have u used any `set.seed` frrom the other answer

Comment: ok, I missed the first part of the link.  I had trouble in replicating it from the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially taking the mean of a logical value - TRUE or FALSE.  Mean is calculating every FALSE value as 0 and every TRUE value as 1.  So in row 2, you have two FALSE values for a mean of (0+0)/2 = 0. In row 1, you have two TRUE values for a mean of (1+1)/2 = 1.

```
sim = matrix(c(1,2,1,2,1,2), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

row2 <- sim[2, sim[1, ] == 1] == 1
row2
mean(row2)

row1 <- sim[1, sim[1, ] == 1] == 1
row1
mean(row1)
```