# Understanding matrix sub-setting: `mat[2, mat[1, ] == 1] == 1` (2)

Tags: r, matrix

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55830847/159072).

I am having trouble understanding the following:

> ```
>    mean(sim[2, sim[1, ] == 1] == 1)
> ```

See the following:

```
> alpha <- c(1, 1) / 2
> mat <- matrix(c(1 / 2, 0, 1 / 2, 1), nrow = 2, ncol = 2) # Different than yours
> 
> chainSim <- function(alpha, mat, n) 
+ {
+   out <- numeric(n)
+   out[1] <- sample(1:2, 1, prob = alpha)
+   
+   for(i in 2:n)
+       out[i] <- sample(1:2, 1, prob = mat[out[i - 1], ])
+   out
+ }
> 
> sim <- replicate(chainSim(alpha, mat, 1 + 5), n = 100)
> 
> x <- (sim[2, sim[1, ] == 1] == 1)
> x
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[15]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[29] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[43]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
>
```

If `x` is composed of only some `true` and `false` values, how could the **mean** of `x` become a numeric value?

```
> sim <- replicate(chainSim(alpha, mat, 1 + 5), n = 100)
> 
> x <- (sim[2, sim[1, ] == 1] == 1)
> y <- mean(x)
> y
[1] 0.6086957
```

Comment: internally, it is 1 and 0, check the `mean(c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0))[1] 0.6#
mean(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))
[1] 0.6`
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP's question

> if x is composed of only some true and false values, how could the mean of x become a numeric value?

According to documentation from `?logical`

> Logical vectors are coerced to integer vectors in contexts where a numerical value is required, with TRUE being mapped to 1L, FALSE to 0L and NA to NA_integer_.

So, taking the `mean` of logical vector is similar to an `integer` vector

```
mean(c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0))
#[1] 0.6

mean(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))
#[1] 0.6
```